# Spectral radius of product of matrices with same left and right eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

Suppose $A, B\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ where $A\mathbf{1}=B\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1}$, $\mathbf{w}^TA=\mathbf{w}^TB=\mathbf{w}^T$, $\mathbf{w}\geq 0$ and $\rho(A)=\rho(B)=1$. Prove that $\rho(AB)=1$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Simulations show that it works. At least when eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are in right half plane. I also know that $AQA-Q\preceq 0$ and $BQB-Q\preceq 0$ with $Q\succeq 0$ satisfy.
I tried mathematically by converting $A$ and $B$ into sum of rank $1$ matrices using eigenvalue decomposition, multiplying and removing the effect of eigenvalue $1$, but it does not work as product of Schur stable matrices may not be a Schur stable matrix. It has something to do with Fiedler eigenvalue, eigenvector pair.

Comment: @Ahsan If $A$ is not a symmetric matrix, then what exactly do you mean by $AQA - Q \preceq 0$? Typically, $M \preceq 0$ presupposes that $M$ is a symmetric matrix; is that not the case here?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, semi-definite programming, where we look at the quadratic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. E.g. when $w\ne0$, since it is also nonnegative, we have $w^T\mathbf1\ne0$. Therefore, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $\mathbf1$ and $\frac{1}{w^T\mathbf1}w^T$ are respectively the first column of $P$ and the first row of $P^{-1}$. The three given conditions in your question thus implies that
$$
P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&X}
\quad\text{and}\quad
P^{-1}BP=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&Y}
$$
for some matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $\rho(X),\rho(Y)\le1$. So, you are essentially asking whether $\rho(X),\rho(Y)\le1\implies\rho(XY)\le1$. The answer is clearly negative, as shown by counterexample below:
$$
X=Y^T=\pmatrix{0&2\\ 0&0},\quad\rho(X)=\rho(Y)=0<1,\quad\rho(XY)=4>1.
$$
To construct a complete counterexample, we may take $w^T=(1,0,0)$,
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 1&1&0\\ 1&0&1},
\quad
P^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ -1&1&0\\ -1&0&1},
$$
$$
A=P(1\oplus X)P^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ -1&0&2\\ 1&0&0},
$$
$$
B=P(1\oplus Y)P^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\ -1&2&0},
$$
$$
AB=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ -3&4&0\\ 1&0&0}.
$$
However, your conjecture is true when $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative matrices. In this case, that $A\mathbf1=B\mathbf1=\mathbf1$ means that the two matrices are stochastic matrices. Hence $AB$ is also stochastic and $\rho(AB)=1$. The condition that $w^TA=w^TB=w^T$ is irrelevant in this case.

**Remark.** Another counterexample. Here we take $w=\mathbf 1$,
$$
X=Y^T=\pmatrix{0&2\\ \frac14&0},
\quad\text{and}\quad P=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 1&-1&1\\ 1&0&-2}
$$
so that each of
$$
A=P(1\oplus X)P^{-1}=\frac{1}{24}
\pmatrix{19&13&-8\\ 3&-3&24\\ 2&14&8},
$$
$$
B=P(1\oplus Y)P^{-1}=\frac{1}{24}\pmatrix{33&-15&6\\ 31&-17&10\\ -40&56&8}
$$
and
$$
AB=\frac{1}{288}\pmatrix{675&-477&90\\ -477&675&90\\ 90&90&108}
$$
is an entrywise nonzero matrix with three distinct eigenvalues. The common spectrum of $A$ and $B$ is $\{1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$ but the eigenvalues of $AB$ are $1,4$ and $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the inciteful example. What happens if we make the geometric multiplicities equal algebraic multiplicity. In your example, eigenvalue $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ and geometric multiplicity $1$. Will the answer remain the same?

Comment: @Ahsan That makes no difference. You may perturb $X$ and $Y$ to make each of them having two different nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, and lastly, will $\mathbf{w}>0$ change anything?

Comment: @Ahsan No. We still have $w^T\mathbf1\ne0$ and hence we can find an appropriate $P$ to construct a counterexample.